# Соотвествие строки символам

Tags: javascript, строки

Формат входных данных:
Дана строка str состоящая из двух символов, строчных букв английского алфавита и цифр. например = b2

Формат выходных данных:
Выведите YES, если она состоит ровно из одной буквы и одной цифры. В противном случае (например str = gt или str == 12 выведите NO.

я делаю так и не работает:

```js
    let s = 'tt';
    let arr = s.split('');
    if (arr[0] || arr[1] == ['A-Za-z']  && arr[0] || arr[1] == [0-9]) {
      console.log('YES');
    } else {
      console.log('NO');
    }
```

Comment: Мне даже страшно предположить откуда вы взяли информацию о подобного рода сравнениях. Сами придумали (`arr[1] == ['A-Za-z']` и `arr[1] == [0-9]`)?

Comment: Можете вообще рассказать что написано в этой строке `if (arr[0] || arr[1] == ['A-Za-z']  && arr[0] || arr[1] == [0-9]) {` ?  Развёрнуто описать каждое выражение.

Comment: Вы задачу пытаетесь решить с помощью регулярных выражений или это был эксперимент?

Comment: извините, я новичок, только учусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Дана строка str состоящая из двух символов, строчных букв английского алфавита и цифр. например = b2

Если строго придерживаться условий, можно предложить такой вариант

```js
let s = 'tt';
if (/[a-z]/.test(s) && /\d/.test(s)) {
  console.log('YES');
} else {
  console.log('NO');
}
```

Или такой...

```js
    let s = 't1';
    if (/[a-z]\d|\d[a-z]/.test(s)) {
      console.log('YES');
    } else {
      console.log('NO');
    }
```